# How to pass arguments as tuple to odeint?

Tags: python, scipy

I wanted to use odeint of scipy with a function

```
def func(y,t,a=123,b=456)
```

then use it as

```
odeint(func,y0,t)
```

If I want to change the values a and b using args

```
odeint(func,y0,t,args=(a=1,b=2))
```

It complains that arguments are not tuple. 
It may be a very elementary question,
how can I pass keyword arguments as a tuple?

```
odeint(func,y0,t,args=...?)
```

Comment: odeint only allows you to pass rest parameters, but not named ones. You can specify additional parameters by position but not by name.

Comment: Does `func` work with `func(1,2,3,4)`?  If so, then `odeint(func,yo,t,args=(1,2))` will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to remove the assignments to make a legit tuple:

```
odeint(func,y0,t,args=(123, 456))
```

[There's another answer here with an example of calling odeint with arguments.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16008005/347567)

Comment: Do you mean (1,2) instead of (a,b)?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but here is my solution:

1. first, we must segment the time we are going to use according to the parameters we are going to use.
2. then, we made a zip(time, a, b) loop, therefore, **a** and **b** must have the same length.

   ```
   def time_segment(tobesimilar, dt:float=0.01):
       '''time_segment produces an array of dt-length time intervals, the shape of the output is ( len(tobesimilar), 2)
       inputs: 
           tobesimilar: array or list, which length (len) is only used as a reference     to be duplicated 
           dt: float, dt refers to what is going to be our integration step, in this case, it is used as the interval length.
       output: 
           tmp: array, such as tmp.shape= (len(tobesimilar),2) 
           '''
       newt=np.arange(0,len(tobesimilar)*dt, dt)

       #segments the nwet[a,b] in n intervals [a_i,b_i]
       #whith a_0 = 0 and b_n = newt[-1] 
        if len(newt)%2==0: #if len(newt) is even, no problem
            tmp = [[newt[i],newt[i+1]] for i in range(len(newt)-1)]
        else: #if len(newt) is odd, just add an item
            newt= np.append(newt,newt[-1]+dt)
            tmp = [[newt[i],newt[i+1]] for i in range(len(newt)-1)]

        #turns tmp into an array cause <3 (heart) numpy
        tmp=np.array(tmp)

        return tmp

   def func(t,y,a=123,b=456):
      return print( "what ever your function does" )

   a=np.array([1,2,3,45,67,88])
   b=np.array([54,4,1,99,42,100])
   y_0= 0 #initial condition
   solution=np.asanyarray([y_0]) #preallocate the output
   time=time_segment(vol, dt=dt)

   for ts in zip(time, a, b):
       y = odeint(func, y0=solution[-1], t=ts[0], args=(ts[1],ts[2],), tfirst= True)
       solution = np.append(solution, [y.T[0][1]])
   ```