# Represent a first order differential equation in numpy

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, derivative

I have an equation `dy/dx = x + y/5` and an initial value, `y(0) = -3`.

I would like to know how to plot the exact graph of this function using pyplot.

I also have a `x = np.linspace(0, interval, steps+1)` which I would like to use as the x axis. So I'm only looking for the y axis values.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to solve your differential equation first.

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001341/having-trouble-while-using-scipy-integrate-odeint-with-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for completeness, this kind of equation can easily be integrated numerically, using `scipy.integrate.odeint`.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# function dy/dx = x + y/5.
func = lambda y,x : x + y/5.
# Initial condition
y0 = -3  # at x=0
# values at which to compute the solution (needs to start at x=0)
x = np.linspace(0, 4, 101)
# solution
y = odeint(func, y0, x)
# plot the solution, note that y is a column vector
plt.plot(x, y[:,0])
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Given that you need to solve the d.e. you might prefer doing this algebraically, with sympy. (Or you might not.)

Import the module and define the function and the dependent variable.

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> f = Function('f')
>>> var('x')
x
```

Invoke the solver. Note that all terms of the d.e. must be transposed to the left of the equals sign, and that the *y* must be replaced by the designator for the function.

```
>>> dsolve(Derivative(f(x),x)-x-f(x)/5)
Eq(f(x), (C1 + 5*(-x - 5)*exp(-x/5))*exp(x/5))
```

As you would expect, the solution is given in terms of an arbitrary constant. We must solve for that using the initial value. We define it as a sympy variable.

```
>>> var('C1')
C1
```

Now we create an expression to represent this arbitrary constant as the left side of an equation that we can solve. We replace *f(0)* with its value in the initial condition. Then we substitute the value of *x* in that condition to get an equation in *C1*.

```
>>> expr = -3 - ( (C1 + 5*(-x - 5)*exp(-x/5))*exp(x/5) )
>>> expr.subs(x,0)
-C1 + 22
```

In other words, C1 = 22. Finally, we can use this value to obtain the particular solution of the differential equation.

```
>>> ((C1 + 5*(-x - 5)*exp(-x/5))*exp(x/5)).subs(C1,22)
((-5*x - 25)*exp(-x/5) + 22)*exp(x/5)
```

Because I'm absentminded and ever fearful of making egregious mistakes I check that this function satisfies the initial condition.

```
>>> (((-5*x - 25)*exp(-x/5) + 22)*exp(x/5)).subs(x,0)
-3
```

(Usually things are incorrect only when I forget to check them. Such is life.)

And I can plot this in sympy too.

```
>>> plot(((-5*x - 25)*exp(-x/5) + 22)*exp(x/5),(x,-1,5))
<sympy.plotting.plot.Plot object at 0x0000000008C2F780>
```

[image: solution to d.e.]