# dsolve error: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

```
import sympy as sp
sp.init_printing()
%matplotlib notebook
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import display
```

[image: Problem]

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: Welcome to SO. [Don't screenshot code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0):

The variable `y` is a numpy.ndarray, not a [callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111234/what-is-a-callable-in-python), which means it cannot be used like a function (or other callable) would: `y()`; only indexed, like `y[]`. You probably meant to write `sp.Derivative(y[x],x)`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you want to solve a differential equation involving only scalar variables.

```
>>> import sympy as sp
>>> sp.var('x')
x
>>> f = sp.Function('f')
>>> sp.dsolve(sp.Derivative(f(x),x)-(1/(1+x**2)-2*f(x)**2))
Eq(f(x), x**3*(2*C1*(C1 - 1) - 1)/3 + x**5*(C1*(16*C1*(-9*C1 + 1) - 13*C1 + 2) - 20*C1 + 12)/30 + C1 + C1*x + C1*x**4*(13*C1 + 2)/6 - C1**2*x**2 + O(x**6))
```

If you have an initial condition and need to solve for the arbitary constant then [Represent a first order differential equation in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42629634/represent-a-first-order-differential-equation-in-numpy/42631638#42631638) might help. (I don't know for sure.)